# How to receive web socket message from server in client side by html5 socket api

Tags: php, javascript, html, websocket

from couple of days i'm fighting with web sockets. But, yet now i couldn't able to get grip on it.

I manage to build a server side file by PHP which is sending message to a particular address+port. But, when i'm trying to access that message in client side by HTML5 socket api, i can't able to get that.

Here is my server side PHP cile code..

```
 $address = "127.0.0.1";
 $service_port = 80;

error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . 
    socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
   echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . 
      socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
}

$in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: www.google.com\r\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
$out = '';

echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
if(!socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not send message on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "OK.\n";
```

In my client side i'm using this following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
// Let us open a web socket
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:80/");
ws.onopen = function()
{
    // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
    ws.send("Message to send");
    alert("Message is sent...");
};
ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
{ 
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    alert("Message is received...");
};
ws.onclose = function()
{ 
    // websocket is closed.
    alert("Connection is closed..."); 
};  
</script>

echo "Reading response:\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    echo "<br><br>$out<br><br>";
}

socket_close($socket);
```

But, i can't able to receive the server side message by using this javascript.

This is the first time i'm trying to put my hand in web sockets. SO, i've totally no idea how to do this. I also search a lot in google but can't able to figure out where & what i'm doing wrong.

Regards

Comment: are you sure your browser supports websockets?

Comment: @KyleK I'm using latest Chrome Version 27.0.1453.116 m.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use another port above 1024 because port under 1024 require root privileges, and this port you use it's already for internet services try to use:

```
$ telnet servername portNumber
```

Test it under shell or cmd and then you can try to use websocket object.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good practice before connecting to websockets, to check if the browser your user is using supports them....like so....

```
 //First check for firefox, and set it to regular websocket...since Mozilla API is                   differently named
if (window.MozWebSocket) {
 window.WebSocket = window.MozWebSocket;
 }

//Then continue with checking
var connection = {};
 function connect() {
 if(window.WebSocket != undefined) {

 if(connection.readyState === undefined || connection.readyState > 1)
  {
    connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:80');
  }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I've tested your script in mozilla but it showing strange behavior. This script is showing my mozilla is not supporting web sockets.
But, when i'm executing the 2nd script it showin 

"Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1/.
connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:80');"

Comment: Is that strange behaviour?? what version are you using?

Comment: My Mozilla is of version : 21.0

Comment: Weird, I found this   http://www.spamfighter.com/News-15538-Websocket-Support-Disabled-in-Opera-and-Firefox-Browsers.htm it could be that you need to enable them?? not sure

Comment: What's that link about ? When i'm clicking on that it showing some "Page not found" error.

Comment: OK, i got that link now. It has mentions may b mozilla has remove support for SOCKET. But, i think chrome is supporting Sockets & at there also it showing same mozilla kind of error.

Comment: Have you tried using a Websocket library for PHP ?  I use Ratchet  http://socketo.me/docs  but there are plenty of others.....also try this https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/